# How to put webPack config file in to node modules?

Tags: webpack, node-modules, webpack-2, webpack-4, local-node-modules

Please help me to find a solution:

I need to create custom webPack config and put it into node_modules? Then I need to use it in any project with the possibility to extend it with local webPack config file.

How to put WebPack global config in node modules?
And how to add the possibility of its extension with local WebPack config?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using https://github.com/layer-pack/layer-pack

You will find different examples that do this [here](https://github.com/layer-pack/layer-pack-samples)

layer-pack also come with various functionality like glob resolving

Hoping it fit you're needs :)